# Modifying a class in Angular to get a new property based on another property

Tags: angular

I've got a class in Angular that looks like the following:

**note.ts**

```
export class Note {
    NoteId: number;
    NoteTitle: string;
    NoteDescription: string;
    Inactive: boolean;
    NoteType: string;
}
```

One field in particular--`NoteType`, is coming from an API as a letter to indicate what kind of note it is, IE: S for Status, Q for Quality, etc. I wanted to add another field in the class to expand on the name of the Type, and call it something like `NoteTypeName`. I tried the following within that class definition:

```
get NoteTypeName(): string {
    switch (this.NoteType) {
    case ("S"):
        return "Status";
    case ("Q"):
        return "Quality";
    ...
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it in my HTML file, it's returning an empty string:

**note-list.html**

```
<mat-card class="nested-card" *ngFor="let note of notes">
    ...
    <div class="card-body">{{ note.NoteType }} | {{ note.NoteTypeName }}</div> <!-- NoteType works, NoteTypeName does not -->
</mat-card>
```

I added a console logging statement in the `get` and it's also not not getting hit from what I can see.

I'm used to doing something like the following in C# and I thought that something like this would be possible in Angular. What am I missing?

```
public string NoteType { get; set; }
public string NoteTypeName
{
    get
    {
        switch (this.NoteType) {
            case ("S"):
                return "Status";
            case ("Q"):
                return "Quality";
            ...
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your switch statement in a callback to ensure that it runs after NoteType is assigned a character. If not, NoteType will still be empty, and the default block in the switch will be triggered causing your empty string. Without more context, that is all I can suggest.

Comment: @NathanToulbert Would it be plausible to call ```NoteTypeName()``` within a ```subscribe``` that gets run after doing a get on the Notes? I shut my environment down for the night and I'm just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a custom pipe for this. I forgot that making your own pipe is possible and saved me some headaches.

**note-type-name.component.ts**

```
@Pipe({name: 'noteTypeName'})
export class NoteTypeNameComponent implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        switch (value) {
            case ("S"):
                return "Status";
            case ("Q"):
                return "Quality";
            ...
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
}
```

**note-list.html**

```
<mat-card class="nested-card" *ngFor="let note of notes">
    ...
    <div class="card-body">{{ note.NoteType | noteTypeName }}</div> <!-- 
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to achieve this is to compute `NoteTypeName` once whenever `Note` is initialized and whenever `NoteType` is modified. This will save recompuation for every rendering cycle.

If performance is not critical, you can define a function like this

```
getNoteTypeName(): string {
    switch (this.NoteType) {
    case ("S"):
        return "Status";
    case ("Q"):
        return "Quality";
    ...
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
```

and call the function inside the *interpolation* `{{..}}` like shown below,

```
<div class="card-body">{{ NoteType }} | {{ getNoteTypeName() }}</div>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-698j7s)

Read this [doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions) to learn about *interpolation*.

Comment: I've been told that calling methods within the template is bad practice. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @LOL.NO. As long as the function is simple and has no side effects as indicated [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-guidelines), it is fine to use functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate note class.

I think you write like this.

```
getNotes(): void {
  this.noteService.getNotes()
      .subscribe(notes => this.notes = notes);
}
```

change like this.

```
getNotes(): void {
  this.noteService.getNotes()
      .subscribe(notes => 
    notes.forEach(note => {
      this.notes.push(new Note(){
        NoteId: note.NoteId,
        NoteTitle: Note.NoteTitle,
        ...
      })
    })
);
}
```

Comment: I left the ```note-list.ts``` code out, but I'm already getting the data for all of the class variables just fine (```NoteId```, ```NoteTitle```, etc.). It's just ```NoteTypeName``` that I'm trying to set/get based on ```NoteType```.

Comment: my sample no need to write  ```NoteTypeName```in ```note-list.ts``` only  rite ```note.ts```. If you don't like to write instantiate logic in ```note-list.ts```, you should write constructor in ```note.ts``` and constructor argument is ```Note```.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has some gotchas compared to C#.

I'm guessing you have something like

```js
this.http.get<Note>(url).subscribe(note => doSomethingWithNote(note)
```

In Typescript, `<Note>` just asserting the type, it's not casting  it.  It's still a plain JS object, and won't have methods that you added to the class.  It just tells your IDE that you're pretty sure this looks like a note object.

You will need to create new Note instances from the data you get back in order to do be able to call the class methods.

```js
// this doesn't make actual Note instances, but will pass the type check...
noInstance(): Observable<Note> {
 return this.http.get<Note>(url);
}

// This makes real Notes (assuming you have a proper constructor that can handle the properties)
instance(): Observable<Note> {
    return this.http.get<Note>(url).pipe(map(note => {
       // if you have a constructor for Note
       return new Note(note);

      // otherwise if no constructor, this can work but you may get additional properties 
      // return Object.assign(new Note(), note)
    )
}


/// somewhere in another file
ngOnInit() {
 this.someService.noInstance().subscribe(note => {
    // typescript will say its a Note, but its not actually an instance of Note, so methods don't work
 })

  this.someService.instance().subscribe(note => {
   // note is a real Note instance here, and methods will work
  })
}
```